# NSStream Failing To Receive Data

Tags: objective-c, sockets, nsstream

I am making a chat application using NSStreams that connect to a simple c socket server. The stream connects successfully, and sends data, but it is unable to receive the data. Here is my Socket class that uses NSStreams:

Socket.h

```
@interface Socket : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate>

- (void)connectToServerWithIP:(NSString *)ip andPort:(int)port;
- (NSString *)sendMessage:(NSString *)outgoingMessage;

@end
```

Socket.m

```
#import "Socket.h"

@interface Socket ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSInputStream *inputStream;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSOutputStream *outputStream;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *output;

@end

@implementation Socket

@synthesize inputStream;
@synthesize outputStream;
@synthesize output;

- (void)connectToServerWithIP:(NSString *)ip andPort:(int)port
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)ip, port, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}

- (NSString *)sendMessage:(NSString *)outgoingMessage
{
    NSData *messageData = [outgoingMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const void *bytes = [messageData bytes];
    uint8_t *uint8_t_message = (uint8_t*)bytes;
    [outputStream write:uint8_t_message maxLength:strlen([outgoingMessage cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]])];
    while (![inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
        usleep(10);
    }
    uint8_t buffer[1024];
    [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:1023];
    NSString *outputString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)buffer];
    return outputString;
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
    NSLog(@"Stream Event: %lu", streamEvent);

    switch (streamEvent) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            if (theStream == inputStream) {
                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                long len;
                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {
                        output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                        if (output) {
                            NSLog(@"Data: %@", output);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            theStream = nil;
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }
}

@end
```

ChatViewController.m

```
//
//  ChatViewController.m
//  Chat
//
//  Created by James Pickering on 10/5/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 James Pickering. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ChatViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "StatusView.h"

@interface ChatViewController ()

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTableView *people;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *message;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSButton *send;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSButton *loginButton;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSButton *settingsButton;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSButton *panicButton;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *recievedText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSInputStream *inputStream;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSOutputStream *outputStream;


- (void)openChat:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)panic:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)loginToChat:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ChatViewController

@synthesize sock;
@synthesize recievedText;
@synthesize inputStream;
@synthesize outputStream;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.isLoggedIn = FALSE;
        sock = [[Socket alloc] init];
        [sock connectToServerWithIP:@"127.0.0.1" andPort:5001];
        //[self updateUI];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)updateUI
{
    if (self.isLoggedIn) {
        recievedText = [sock sendMessage:@"getPeople"];
        self.tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[recievedText componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.tableData);
        [self.people reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)openChat:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"tru");
}

- (IBAction)panic:(id)sender {

}

- (IBAction)loginToChat:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Called");
    if (self.loginPopover == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Login Popover is nil");
        self.loginPopover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
        self.loginPopover.contentViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    if (!self.loginPopover.isShown) {
        NSLog(@"Login Popover is opening");
        [self.loginButton setTitle:@"Cancel"];
        [self.settingsButton setEnabled:NO];
        [self.send setEnabled:NO];
        [self.message setEnabled:NO];
        [self.loginPopover showRelativeToRect:self.loginButton.frame ofView:self.view preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Login Popover is closing");
        [self.loginButton setTitle:@"Login"];
        [self.settingsButton setEnabled:YES];
        [self.send setEnabled:YES];
        [self.message setEnabled:YES];
        [self.loginPopover close];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    return [self.tableData count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return [self.tableData objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)loginWithUsername:(NSString *)username andPassword:(NSString *)password
{
    // Error happens here

    recievedText = [sock sendMessage:@"login"];
    if ([recievedText isEqualToString:@"roger"]) {
        recievedText = [sock sendMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@;%@", username, password]];
        if ([recievedText isEqualToString:@"access granted"]) {
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}

@end
```

The problem is that it hangs on this one line of code forever: `while (![inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {}`, but I have no idea why. The server should be sending a message back.

Comment: I'm facing same issue...any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, looking at your `NSStreamDelegate`, it looks like you haven't implemented all of the cases for that switch statement. I recently wrote an IRC client for OS X that uses `NSStream` and `NSStreamDelegate` in a very similar way, and I'm pretty sure that the compiler should complain when you haven't checked for all of the cases there.

Looking back to [some of my code](https://github.com/tjarratt/twIRCk/blob/master/TwIRCk/GLGReadDelegate.m) it looks like you should be checking for the cases

- `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`
- `NSStreamEventOpenCompleted`
- `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable`
- `NSStreamEventEndEncountered`
- `NSStreamEventErrorOccurred`

So the case you haven't checked for is `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`, which is when you can start writing to your stream.

edit: Reading your code again, I see in your `sendMessage` action that you're using the `outputStream` object instead of the delegate to write, and then doing the work yourself to read from the `inputStream`. I think you probably want to use the delegate and never read directly from your inputstream because it will greatly simplify how your code receives data from the network. From what I understand, `NSStream` is there to provide a small layer of abstraction around the fact that data is buffered from the network so you don't need to do things like call `usleep` while your inputstream does not have bytes available to read.

edit2: I read your update about your code never getting past `while (![inputStream hasBytesAvailable])` and it seems pretty clear that the problem is that you're not using your streams correctly. The way I see it, the best way to use `NSStream` is to respond to events, using its `handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent) event` method, and never directly tell it to write bytes, or to sleep until it has bytes available.

In the code I linked to you, I have a readDelegate and a writeDelegate that both handle `NSStreams`, you might want to take a look at how I use my writeDelegate [here](https://github.com/tjarratt/twIRCk/blob/master/TwIRCk/GLGWriteDelegate.m). I basically have a method, `addCommand:(NSString *) command` that puts a string to write to the stream into a queue, and then when my stream delegate can write bytes (`NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`), I write as many bytes as I can. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for responding. The reason I have the input stream doing that is because I don't want it returning nil if there are no bytes available, so I loop until it has something to return. The funny thing is that when I take the `if(isLoggedIn)` line out of the code, the code in update UI works perfectly, both sending and receiving data. I am looking into your suggestion and I hope it works.

Comment: There is nothing 'NSStreamHasSpaceAvailable' instead there is 'NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable'.